# Avoid Resharper to add a region per Declaration

Tags: c#, resharper, regions

i have some trouble configuring the "Type Members Layout" of Resharper 7.1.3.

I started using the template for using with regions and tried to customized it for my needs.

P L E A S E: No discussion about "not using regions, etc. ..."

My first problem is, that he is currently creating one region per field declaration in code, but of course i want to have ONE region with "Static Fields and Constants" and ONE region with "Fields and Constants".

The second problem is that he does not create a single region for my "Constructors". It seems that he just accepts the first two "Patterns" in the configuration but ignores the others.?!

See here the multiple Regions Problem:

[image: too many regions]

My Type Members Layout looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!--
I. Overall

I.1 Each pattern can have <Match>....</Match> element. For the given type declaration, the pattern with the match, evaluated to 'true' with the largest weight, will be used 
I.2 Each pattern consists of the sequence of <Entry>...</Entry> elements. Type member declarations are distributed between entries
I.3 If pattern has RemoveAllRegions="true" attribute, then all regions will be cleared prior to reordering. Otherwise, only auto-generated regions will be cleared
I.4 The contents of each entry is sorted by given keys (First key is primary,  next key is secondary, etc). Then the declarations are grouped and en-regioned by given property

II. Available match operands

Each operand may have Weight="..." attribute. This weight will be added to the match weight if the operand is evaluated to 'true'.
The default weight is 1

II.1 Boolean functions:
II.1.1 <And>....</And>
II.1.2 <Or>....</Or>
II.1.3 <Not>....</Not>

II.2 Operands
II.2.1 <Kind Is="..."/>. Kinds are: class, struct, interface, enum, delegate, type, constructor, destructor, property, indexer, method, operator, field, constant, event, member
II.2.2 <Name Is="..." [IgnoreCase="true/false"] />. The 'Is' attribute contains regular expression
II.2.3 <HasAttribute CLRName="..." [Inherit="true/false"] />. The 'CLRName' attribute contains regular expression
II.2.4 <Access Is="..."/>. The 'Is' values are: public, protected, internal, protected internal, private
II.2.5 <Static/>
II.2.6 <Abstract/>
II.2.7 <Virtual/>
II.2.8 <Override/>
II.2.9 <Sealed/>
II.2.10 <Readonly/>
II.2.11 <ImplementsInterface CLRName="..."/>. The 'CLRName' attribute contains regular expression
II.2.12 <HandlesEvent />
-->

<Patterns xmlns="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:member-reordering-patterns">

    <!--Do not reorder COM interfaces and structs marked by StructLayout attribute-->
    <Pattern>
        <Match>
            <Or Weight="100">
                <And>
                    <Kind Is="interface"/>
                    <Or>
                        <HasAttribute CLRName="System.Runtime.InteropServices.InterfaceTypeAttribute"/>
                        <HasAttribute CLRName="System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComImport"/>
                    </Or>
                </And>
                <HasAttribute CLRName="System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute"/>
            </Or>
        </Match>
    </Pattern>

    <!--Special formatting of NUnit test fixture-->
    <Pattern RemoveAllRegions="true">
        <Match>
            <And Weight="100">
                <Kind Is="class"/>
                <HasAttribute CLRName="NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute" Inherit="true"/>
            </And>
        </Match>

        <!--Setup/Teardow-->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                <And>
                    <Kind Is="method"/>
                    <Or>
                        <HasAttribute CLRName="NUnit.Framework.SetUpAttribute" Inherit="true"/>
                        <HasAttribute CLRName="NUnit.Framework.TearDownAttribute" Inherit="true"/>
                        <HasAttribute CLRName="NUnit.Framework.FixtureSetUpAttribute" Inherit="true"/>
                        <HasAttribute CLRName="NUnit.Framework.FixtureTearDownAttribute" Inherit="true"/>
                    </Or>
                </And>
            </Match>
            <Group Region="Setup/Teardown"/>
        </Entry>

        <!--All other members-->
        <Entry/>

        <!--Test methods-->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                <And Weight="100">
                    <Kind Is="method"/>
                    <HasAttribute CLRName="NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute" Inherit="false"/>
                </And>
            </Match>
            <Sort>
                <Name/>
            </Sort>
        </Entry>
    </Pattern>

    <Pattern RemoveAllRegions="true">
        <!-- static fields and constants -->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                    <Or>
                        <And>
                            <Kind Is="constant"/>
                            <Static/>
                        </And>              
                        <And>
                            <Kind Is="field"/>
                            <Static/>
                        </And>                              
                    </Or>

            </Match>
            <Sort>
                <Readonly/>
                <Name/>
            </Sort>
            <Group>
                <Name Region="Static Fields and Constants"/>
            </Group>
        </Entry>

        <!--fields and constants-->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                    <Or>
                        <And>
                            <Kind Is="constant"/>
                            <Not>
                                <Static/>
                            </Not>
                        </And>              
                        <And>
                            <Kind Is="field"/>
                            <Not>
                                <Static/>
                            </Not>
                        </And>                  
                    </Or>
            </Match>
            <Sort>
                <Readonly/>
                <Name/>
            </Sort>
            <Group>
                <Name Region="Fields and Constants"/>
            </Group>
        </Entry>
    </Pattern>

    <!--Default pattern-->
    <Pattern RemoveAllRegions="false">

        <!--public delegate-->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                <And Weight="100">
                    <Access Is="public"/>
                    <Kind Is="delegate"/>
                </And>
            </Match>
            <Sort>
                <Name/>
            </Sort>
            <Group Region="Delegates"/>
        </Entry>

        <!--public enum-->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                <And Weight="100">
                    <Access Is="public"/>
                    <Kind Is="enum"/>
                </And>
            </Match>
            <Sort>
                <Name/>
            </Sort>
            <Group>
                <Name Region="${Name} enum"/>
            </Group>
        </Entry>

        <!-- Constructors. Place static one first -->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                <Kind Is="constructor"/>
            </Match>
            <Sort>
                <Static/>
            </Sort>
            <Group>
                <Name Region="Constructor / Destructor"/>
            </Group>
        </Entry>

        <!--properties, indexers-->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                <Or>
                    <Kind Is="property"/>
                    <Kind Is="indexer"/>
                </Or>
            </Match>
            <Group Region="Properties"/>
        </Entry>

        <!--interface implementations-->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                <And Weight="100">
                    <Kind Is="member"/>
                    <ImplementsInterface/>
                </And>
            </Match>
            <Sort>
                <ImplementsInterface Immediate="true"/>
            </Sort>
            <Group>
                <ImplementsInterface Immediate="true" Region="${ImplementsInterface} Members"/>
            </Group>
        </Entry>

        <!--all other members-->
        <Entry/>

        <!--nested types-->
        <Entry>
            <Match>
                <Kind Is="type"/>
            </Match>
            <Sort>
                <Name/>
            </Sort>
            <Group>
                <Name Region="Nested type: ${Name}"/>
            </Group>
        </Entry>
    </Pattern>
</Patterns>
```

Would be cool, if someone could give me the hint ;)

cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried writing

```
<Group Region="Static Fields and Constants"/>
```

instead of

```
 <Group>
     <Name Region="Static Fields and Constants"/>
 </Group>
```

?

As for your second problem - you've created two default patterns. Rules for "Static Fields and Constants" and "Fields and Constants" came to the first pattern and rules for constuctors came to the second pattern. Seems like ReSharper accepts the first matching pattern and ignores all others. You need to remove these lines to combine your patterns:

```
</Pattern>

<!--Default pattern-->
<Pattern RemoveAllRegions="false">
```

Comment: Hi, big thanx for your fast response. It works like a charm ;)! But, the reason why i used multiple "Pattern"s was, that i wanted the Resharper to cleanup Regions within the Fields and Constants Regions but want it to leave the Regions in the methods, properties, etc. alone. Because sometimes i use regions to group special methods. If i would use the "Cleanup Code" Resharper would destroy my custom regions. :(

Comment: @ChrisTTian667 Unfortunately, it is now impossible to remove regions selectively.